# Separate internal HDD for specific Home folders?

Tags: hard-drive, home-directory, fstab

Is it possible to edit fstab or reinstall Ubuntu where /home/pictures, /home/music, and /home/videos are all stored in a second internal HDD, SDB? The other /home folders would be stored on the other internal HDD, SDA.

If so, what's the simplist way to do so?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

What you want can easily be achieved.

All you need to do is create a mount point to that disk (`gparted` is the easiest tool for that). If you already have a mount point setting the directories up can be done with  `.config/user-dirs.dirs`. Full content:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Change `$HOME` for the mount point. You can use `/discworld/$HOME/Downloads` for instance where `/discworld` is the mount point.

Tip: keep a copy of `user-dirs.dirs` on your partition so you can copy/paste it when you re-install your system.